# NSSlider NSSliderCell clipping custom knob

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsslider

I am creating a custom NSSlider with a custom NSSliderCell. All is working beautifully, other than the knob. When I drag it to the max value the knob is being clipped, I can only see 50% of the knob image.

When assigning my custom NSSliderCell I am setting the knobThickness to the width of the image I am using as the knob. I assumed (I guess wrongly) that it would take that into account and stop it from clipping?

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? The slider is hitting the maxValue only when the knob is clipped at 50%, so its not travelling without adding any value.

```
- (void)drawKnob:(NSRect)knobRect {
 NSImage * knob = _knobOff;
 knobRectVar = knobRect;

 [[self controlView] lockFocus];
 [knob
  compositeToPoint:
  NSMakePoint(knobRect.origin.x+4,knobRect.origin.y+knobRect.size.height+20)
  operation:NSCompositeSourceOver];
 [[self controlView] unlockFocus];
}

- (void)drawBarInside:(NSRect)rect flipped:(BOOL)flipped {
 rect.size.height = 8;

 [[self controlView] lockFocus];
 NSImage *leftCurve = [NSImage imageNamed:@"customSliderLeft"];
 [leftCurve drawInRect:NSMakeRect(5, 25, 8, 8) fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1];

    NSRect leftRect = rect;
    leftRect.origin.x=13;
    leftRect.origin.y=25;
    leftRect.size.width = knobRectVar.origin.x + (knobRectVar.size.width/2);
    [leftBarImage setSize:leftRect.size];
    [leftBarImage drawInRect:leftRect fromRect: NSZeroRect operation: NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1];
 [[self controlView] unlockFocus];

}
```

Answer (score 4):

The NSSLider expects a special sizes off the knob images for each control size:

```
NSRegularControlSize:   21x21
NSSmallControlSize:     15x15
NSMiniControlSize:      12x12
```

Unfortunately the height of your knob image mustn't exceed one of this parameters. But it's width may be longer. If it is you may count an x position for the knob like this:

```
CGFloat newOriginX = knobRect.origin.x *
        (_barRect.size.width - (_knobImage.size.width - knobRect.size.width)) / _barRect.size.width;
```

Where _barRect is a cellFrame of your bar background from:

```
- (void)drawBarInside:(NSRect)cellFrame flipped:(BOOL)flipped;
```

I've created a simple solution for the custom NSSlider. Follow this link
https://github.com/Doshipak/LADSlider

Answer (score 4):

You can override `[NSSliderCell knobRectFlipped:]` in addition to `[NSSliderCell drawKnob:]`.
Here is my solution:

```
- (void)drawKnob:(NSRect)rect
{
  NSImage *drawImage = [self knobImage];

  NSRect drawRect = [self knobRectFlipped:[self.controlView isFlipped]];

  CGFloat fraction = 1.0;

  [drawImage drawInRect:drawRect fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:fraction respectFlipped:YES hints:nil];
}

- (NSRect)knobRectFlipped:(BOOL)flipped
{
  NSImage *drawImage = [self knobImage];

  NSRect drawRect = [super knobRectFlipped:flipped];

  drawRect.size = drawImage.size;

  NSRect bounds = self.controlView.bounds;
  bounds = NSInsetRect(bounds, ceil(drawRect.size.width / 2), 0);
  CGFloat val = MIN(self.maxValue, MAX(self.minValue, self.doubleValue));
  val = (val - self.minValue) / (self.maxValue - self.minValue);
  CGFloat x = val * NSWidth(bounds) + NSMinX(bounds);

  drawRect = NSOffsetRect(drawRect, x - NSMidX(drawRect) + 1, 0);
  return drawRect;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Know it's been awhile but I ran into this issue myself and found a quick-and-dirty workaround.

I couldn't get around the initial reason for this but it seems that NSSlider is expecting a quadratic handle image.
The easiest way I found was to set the range of your slider to be from 0.0f - 110.0f for example.

Then you check in the valueChanged target method assigned if the value is > 100.0f and set it back to that value if it is. I created a background image with some pixels of alpha-only pixels on the right side so your background isn't wider than the actual fader range.

Quick-and-dirty but doesn't require a lot code and works pretty well.
Hope this helps other guys stumbling upon the same issue.

Answer (score -2):

You don’t need to lock and unlock focus on the controlView from inside cell drawing methods.  These methods are only called by your controlView’s -drawRect: method, which is called with the view’s focus locked.

Why are you adding 20 points to the Y coordinate the knob image is composited to in -drawKnob?

Comment: it draws the knob with 50% clipped and not centered on the bar without the +20.0

Comment: btw - was this an answer to the problem? I removed the code you mentioned and it made no difference.

Comment: I suggest you try overriding -knobRectFlipped: and calculate the knob rect based on the current value of the slider, and then don’t do any other adjustments in -drawKnob:.  My reason for suggesting this is that possibly the drawing context is being clipped to the knobRect right before -drawKnob: is called.  Can I see some screenshots of the slider at the median and maximum values?